# Use asp.net authentication with servicestack

Tags: asp.net, authentication, servicestack

I have written a couple of ms lightswitch applications with forms authentication -> this creates aspnet_* tables in sql server.
How can I use the defined users, passwords, maybe even memberships, roles and application rights in a servicestack - application?

Comment: Think this answer has the resources you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711436/use-asp-net-membership-in-servicestack

Comment: I have already studied this answer, it is not what I need. This answer  tells me how to use forms authentication and servicestack authentications side by side, what I want to do is to use forms authentication directly in servicestack.

Answer (score 6):

I have not tested this but I think it should get you started. Gladly stand corrected on any of my steps.

Things I think you will need to do..

- In order to Authenticate against both 'systems' you'll need to set the Forms cookie and save your ServiceStack session.

Instead of calling `FormsAuthentication.Authentiate()` do something like below. This won't work until you complete all the steps.

```
var apiAuthService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
apiAuthService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
var apiResponse = apiAuthService.Authenticate(new Auth
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Password = model.Password,
    RememberMe = false
});
```

- Create a subclass of `IUserAuthRepository` (for retrieving membership/user/roles from aspnet_* tables and filling ServiceStack AuthUser).

CustomAuthRepository.cs (incomplete, but should get you started)

```
public class CustomAuthRepository : IUserAuthRepository
{
    private readonly MembershipProvider _membershipProvider;
    private readonly RoleProvider _roleProvider;

    public CustomAuthRepository()
    {
        _membershipProvider = Membership.Provider;
        _roleProvider = Roles.Provider;
    }

    public UserAuth GetUserAuthByUserName(string userNameOrEmail)
    {
        var user = _membershipProvider.GetUser(userNameOrEmail, true);
        return new UserAuth {FirstName = user.UserName, Roles = _roleProvider.GetRolesForUser(userNameOrEmail).ToList() //FILL IN REST OF PROPERTIES};
    }

    public bool TryAuthenticate(string userName, string password, out UserAuth userAuth)
    {
        //userId = null;
        userAuth = GetUserAuthByUserName(userName);
        if (userAuth == null) return false;

        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(userName, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
            return true;
        }

        userAuth = null;
        return false;
    }
//MORE METHODS TO IMPLEMENT...
}
```

- Wire Authentication up for ServiceStack in AppHost configure method.

  ```
  var userRep = new CustomAuthRepository();

  container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

  Plugins.Add(
      new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
          new IAuthProvider[] {
              new CredentialsAuthProvider() 
          }
      ));
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will help to get me started, I will do my fist steps and maybe get back to you? Best Regards